# Cierre de ventana después de ejecutar driver.get

Tags: python, selenium

Mi problema es que cuando abro una ventana con el comando de driver.get('cualquier URL') con selenium python, automáticamente se abre y se cierra en un par de segundos luego de mostrármela, deseo que se mantenga abierta hasta que yo lo desee, he visto tutoriales y en todos ellos después de ejecutar el código la ventana se mantiene abierta, estoy haciendo uso de  msvcrt.getch() para que se mantenga abierta hasta que yo lo diga, pero no es natural y además siempre me arroja por consola "DevTools listening on ws://"numeros"/devtools", no se si tenga algo que ver.

```
options =  webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('--start-maximized')

driver = webdriver.Chrome(service = Service('C:/chromedriver_win32/chromedriver.exe'), options=options)
driver.get('https://www.facebook.com/')
```

Comment: Jorge, edita la pregunta y añade el código del como estas abierto el navegador con selenium, si no compartes el código solo nos queda especular una respuesta

Comment: Quizá se está cerrando porque el script termina. Ahora mismo no recuerdo si eso podía pasar.

Comment: Hola Jorge, para tu problema piensa lo siguiente. Una vez que selenium realiza la carga de la pagina es decir realiza ese paso ¿el siguiente cual es? si no hay otro paso el navegador se cierra. Lo que tienes que hacer es definir otro paso post cargado de la url y trabajarlo con esperas explicititas o implicitas.

Answer (score -4):

Es posible que el problema se deba a que el navegador se está cerrando de manera automática después de cierto tiempo de inactividad. Una solución para esto sería añadir una opción en las opciones del navegador para evitar que se cierre. Esto se puede hacer agregando la siguiente línea de código después de crear el objeto options:

```
options.add_argument('--disable-infobars')
```

De esta manera, se deshabilitará la opción que cierra el navegador después de cierto tiempo de inactividad.

En cuanto al mensaje que aparece en la consola, "DevTools listening on ws://"numeros"/devtools", se refiere a que las herramientas para desarrolladores de Chrome (DevTools) están siendo utilizadas por el controlador de Selenium. Este mensaje no debería afectar el funcionamiento de tu código, por lo que no debería preocuparte.

Comment: Relacionado: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5450/cheatgpt-chatgpt-nos-ha-alcanzado-en-soes

Comment: Usar chatGPT está prohibido en [es.so], además, usar chatGPT sin citar la fuente es considerado [Plagio](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plagio). Relacionado: [cheatGPT (chatGPT) nos ha alcanzado en SOes](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5450/cheatgpt-chatgpt-nos-ha-alcanzado-en-soes), [Temporary policy: ChatGPT is banned](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421831/temporary-policy-chatgpt-is-banned). Tu cuenta puede ser suspendida por este motivo.